# Window not wanting to run on something that should run in java

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a program with a friend and it doesn't want to run because the only thing in the program is erroring, the window, and it doesn't show the error or a fix to it.

This is also my dirst time on stack Overflow

Code:

```
package examplepackage;
//imports
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import examplepackage.GetFilepath;

public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GetFilepath FP = new GetFilepath();
        JFrame win1 = new JFrame("windowname");
        win1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        win1.getContentPane().add(win1, FlowLayout.LEFT, FlowLayout.LEADING);
        win1.pack();
        win1.setVisible(true);
        win1.setLocationRelativeTo(win1);
        win1.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(FP + "\\window\\Main").getImage());
    }

}
```

Comment: What is happening exactly when you try to run this?

Comment: Kon,
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at net.MMMGames.JAVIS.Starter.main(Starter.java:16)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
win1.getContentPane().add(win1, FlowLayout.LEFT, FlowLayout.LEADING);
```

makes no sense. You appear to be trying to add a component to itself(??) something that can't be done, shouldn't be done, and is a bit strange looking, and then on top of this you are also passing in FlowLayout constants that don't belong in an `add(...)` method. The whole thing doesn't belong so get rid of it. It makes me wonder -- what were you trying to achieve with this line?

---

**Edit**
Your comments show a link to this tutorial page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

In the page, it shows this code:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

which looks nothing like yours. The line adds a JLabel to a JFrame's contentPane in the BorderLayout.CENTER position. That makes sense since the contentPane uses BorderLayout by default, and since you're trying to add a component, a JLabel to the JFrame's contentPane. You on the other hand are trying to add the same JFrame to its own contentPane and doing so using a FlowLayout constants in a way that they are never used. I'm not sure how you got your code from this recommendation. It still boggles my mind.

---

**Edit 2**
Note that the FlowLayout constants do have a use, but not as you're using them. You use them when creating a FlowLayout object where you want to specify the state of the layout. For instance:

```
FlowLayout myFlowLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(myFlowLayout);
```

Or the similar but more brief code which does the same thing:

```
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

Even when doing this, you would never combine FlowLayout.LEFT and FlowLayout.LEADING together in on the same line. And you would never use them when adding a component to a FlowLayout-using (or any layout using) container.

Comment: thank you, i was on the oracle page for this and they said to put that line

Comment: @MMMGamesGameDevCo: the hell they did. Show me the page that tells you to add a component to itself, that tells you to use FlowLayout constants in an add method.

Comment: it told me to use BorderLayout

Comment: @MMMGamesGameDevCo.: most important though is to look critically at the line causing your errors, and try to see what is wrong. If you look at that line and the tutorials, you'll see in an instant that it doesn't make sense, that it is not what they are suggesting you do.

Comment: @MMMGamesGameDevCo.: huh? you have no BorderLayout code in your posted code. Again, show the link to the tutorial that tells you this.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html also the page you wanted

Comment: `frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);` This line?

Comment: @MMMGamesGameDevCo.: please see edit to answer. Please re-read the tutorial critically.

Comment: i got that line from thenewboston on youtube, i'm an ameture at windows in java

Comment: "_i was on the oracle page for this and they said to put that line_" Now it came from youtube? @MMMGamesGameDevCo. Honestly I'm not trying to be harsh but you must understand how difficult it is to help you when we receive such fragmented info.

Comment: @MMMGamesGameDevCo.: no trust me, you are misinterpreting something as you will not find that line anywhere as it is not legal Swing code for more than one reason. But regardless, read the tutorial that you've linked to as it will show you how to do things right.

Comment: @Takendarkk: I know, everything is shifting.

Comment: thank you, I pretty much know how to do everything from here

Comment: @MMMGamesGameDevCo.: OK. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Actually one more thing...WTF do I put for the emptyLabel, it won't run with it.

Comment: @Takendarkk I know your not trying to be harsh, but this is also my first time using stackoverflow

Comment: First time on this site or not you should realize that giving us false info will result in incorrect or at least incomplete answers.

Comment: @Takendarkk the original base for the class came from the link, but that didn't fully resolve my issue, then i went to thenewboston on YouTube and the both of them did it completely different ways, one used    super();     and the other used what I gave you since his stuff errored, but he was the one that used FlowLayout

Comment: @MMMGamesGameDevCo.: please see edit regarding the FlowLayout specifiers. Note that the New Boston tutorial may have used FlowLayout and its specifiers, but never in a way that you have used it, not even in the same context. They are used for setting up the layout, not for adding components to the layout. Also I'm still confused as to why you were trying to add a JFrame to its own contentPane. It's similar to trying to add you to yourself.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not doing that now, there error is at the label